# jQuery animate div that is dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that is being created in one of six locations (columns) and I then want these newly created divs (.letter-block).  It should create a new block each second and these blocks need to "fall" to the bottom of the container column div (or stop at the top of last block in that column so as to get the effect the blocks are stacking on top of each other, similar to Tetris).  I can get the blocks to create but once created, they don't "fall" to the bottom of the container div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(newLetter, 1000)
    function newLetter(){
    var $randCol = $("#col" + (Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1));
   $randCol.prepend("<div class='letter-block'></div>").animate({'bottom':'0'}, 500);
    };
});
```

Comment: make jsfiddle so its easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
var $randCol = $("#col" + (Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1));
$randCol.prepend("<div class='letter-block'></div>").animate({'bottom':'0'}, 500);
```

The element that is selected here is one of your six columns.  You prepend the new `<div>`, but the column is still what is selected, so you are trying to animate the column instead of the new `<div>`.  Then you need to calculate how many blocks you are sitting on top of. Count the number of blocks in the column and then multiply that by their height, that is you new bottom position.  Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(newLetter, 1000);
    function newLetter(){
        var $randCol = $("#col" + (Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1));
        var $newDiv = $("<div class='letter-block'></div>");
        $randCol.prepend($newDiv);
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $oldBlocks = $randCol.find('.letter-block');
            var yPos = '' + ($oldBlocks.length * $oldBlocks.first().outerHeight());
            $newDiv.animate({
                'bottom': yPos
            }, 500);
        });
    };
});
```

Make sure that the new div is `position: absolute` or `position: relative` (probably absolute in your case) or directional properties like `bottom` won't work on it.  CSS:

```
.letter-block {
    position: absolute;
    // other CSS
}
```

Comment: This still does not animate the create blocks, I know that it is because these elements didn't exist when the document is ready so it doesn't recognize any '.letter-block' elements, but the only way I know to get them is through $(document).on but then an event is required, which I don't have.  I need the animation to happen immediately on creation

Comment: `.letter-block {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 39px;
    width: 39px;
    background-color: #3399FF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: absolute;
}`

It had been relative, changing to absolute does allow the animation to work, but it doesn't keep them from overlapping now.  Before, they would not overlap (the newest created one would create on top and push the last one down) but now they animate and no longer stack up, just on top of each other

Comment: Ok, I overlooked that in your question, I just assumed the `animate` was fine as long as it was working.  This is a little more complicated, because as soon as you can persuade an element to be positioned `bottom: 0` it is going to conflict with anything else that is forced to be there.  You are going to have to do a little math and figure out exactly where you want each new div to go.  I'll update my answer with some code in a minute. Honestly, it would be nice if we could just use `float: down`, but you can only float left and right :(

Comment: I believe I have figured it out, I just created a variable to count the number of `.letter-block` divs in the $randCol column and set it to animate to 310 (bottom) - 40*len where len is the number of `.letter-block` in the column.  Thank you so much for the help though! I really appreciate it.